# Statistics about types of timber used in buildings

Tags: materials

Is there any article, published anywhere, listing the types of timber used in buildings? If it is detailed, saying what kind of timber is used in structural parts and making a list by percentage, then doing the same for the other parts of the building it would be great.

A list of the types of timber used to make plywood and other engineered panels and components would be useful as well.

Comment: It will depend on what part of the world and the type of building and "components".

Comment: @blacksmith37 Yes, I know. Any statistic is fine if there is more than one reference, I'll compare the geographical context, but I suspect there won't be many resources.

Comment: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:16598:ed-1:v1:en

Comment: Timber types are specified for structures according to their mechanical properties. Pretty much every kind of timber has been used structurally around the world. They key is fitness for the task. Unlikely to find useful statistics on this sort of thing but you never know until they are found.

Comment: @Rhodie That is why I asked this question. All the qwant/google/bing searches are spammed by results that group materials in hardwood and softwood, but that is not what I was looking for. I barely know that pine and spruce are the most used types, I also know that oak and ash are frequently used, but I was searching for a statistics that goes down all the list.